# Make a relative position div follow a fixed position div when scrolling

Tags: css, html, css-position

so here's my problem. I have two divs, and i want to be able to see both of them when i scroll down the page. Both divs are in the same parent container. If i give the parent a position:fixed, the the bottom div get's cut off, because you have to scroll to see it's full height. So i tried this. I gave position:fixed to the top div, and position relative to the bottom one. The fixed one now scrools but the relative doesn't "follow it" or stay beneath it.

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle to receive useful answers

Comment: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LC3zw/ ... so, the silver div is fixed, and the red should always stay below it when scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the answer is to position both divs absolutely within the fixed parent.

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5M7cL/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="topDiv"></div>
    <div class="bottomDiv"></div>
</div
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    height:1500px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    position: fixed;
}
.topDiv {
    display:block;
    background:silver;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
}
.bottomDiv {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    left:0
}
```